# Get DataContext from UserControl

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I have a user control whose datacontext is set with this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <data:ArchivosViewModel x:Key="Data" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In this user control I want to load a grid view with a list of objects in 5 columns with several values (date, url, name... and a button to delete each row).

To add this button I want to use a command that I have in my UserControl ViewModel and a CommandParameter wich I'll have in my datagrid source datacontext.

I think the best way to do this would be to set the datacontext in that button to the staticresource but it is not working... Any idea of how to do this?

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Ficheros, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" SelectionMode="Single"  Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fecha">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <sdk:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding fecha_fichero, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5,0" Width="Auto"></sdk:DatePicker>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding nombre_fichero, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="Nombre" Width="Auto" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding descripcion_fichero, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" CanUserSort="True" Header="Descripción" Width="Auto" />
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Enlace">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <HyperlinkButton Margin="5,0" Width="Auto" NavigateUri="{Binding ruta_fichero, Mode=OneWay}" TargetName="_blank" Content="Abrir Fichero"></HyperlinkButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Eliminar">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Width="Auto" Margin="5,0" Content="Eliminar Fichero" Command="{Binding EliminarArchivoCommand}" ></Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
 Command="{Binding EliminarArchivoCommand,Source={StaticResource Data}}"
```

and :

```
CommandArgument="{Binding}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!

This is not the problem, it's working good for everything but the last column which I want to have a binding to the items datacontext (for the command parameter) and another to the Data datacontext (for the command).

Comment: sorry, misunderstood the question. Take al ook at my edit... I think this should work

Comment: Finally this isn't working :(. It executes but XAML is marking it as an error and, for example, OnCanExecute is not been executed :(